# Place a CheckBox in a ListViewSubItem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to create a WinForms ListView control with 6 columns. The first two columns will have text in them, but I want the last four columns to have a checkbox in them.

I know how to add a ListViewSubItem with text (did this for the second column), but how do you insert a CheckBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListView doesn't support this.  Only the 1st column can have a checkbox.  You could fake it with custom drawing and mouse hit testing but that's a lot of work.  Consider using a DataGridView instead.  You can change the column type to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.

Comment: Awesome...that was exactly what I was looking for.  Didn't even think to look for another control other than listbox.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you define the columns for the ListView, you have to change the type to checkbox