# c# Controlling Checkboxes within a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox

I have been using the `Listview`'s `Checkboxes` property to add a single checkbox control to each row in my `ListView`.

There is one problems with this however:

**Issue:** The `CheckBoxes` property only adds the checkbox in front of the *first* column. I would like a checkbox *after* the *last* column (if at all possible).

What I would like my ListView to look like:

```
| Column Header 1 | Column Header 2 | Column Header 3 |
    "some data"       "more data"      'CheckBox' Here
```

Thank you very much for any help with this!

Evan

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible (or at least not easily).

If feasible, I'd suggest you to switch to a `DataGridView`, that gives you more control over columns types, and allows you to create one or more [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx) columns wherever you want.

Comment: See Hans answer here for more info, [only the first column can be a checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/545888/495455)